# Salesforce Community - Set content width max with in PX instead of %

Tags: community, css, community-builder

I'm trying to set the max width of the community section to be 1000px, however the controls in the community only let be adjust by % and not by px.

[image: community settings]

I've been trying to override using CSS but can't seem to find the relevant class to change as the max-width shows as inline CSS when published.

Any ideas how I can set the max-width by pixels instead of %?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Experience builder, click on Theme(brush icon on the left side) then click on edit CSS which will open the modal, then click on use overrides and add the below CSS

```
.siteforceStarterBody .cCenterPanel{
   width : 1000px
}
```

Hopefully this fill fix your issue

Thanks